# Caching plugins will affect the wordpress shop stock control?

Tags: wordpress

To avoid a lot of memory consuption on my server. I am thinking to activate server caching and using wordpress caching plugins as well.

However, my wordpress is an online store. So, I am unsure that how it'd work out. Like will enabling caching will cause delays in the stock control in woocommerce?
Like I am afraid if a customer buys an item, it wont be reduced by 1 immediately because of the caching plugin?

Let me know if that is the case?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cache plugin with a Wordpress powered online stores, but you must exclude all store related pages from being cached so that they remain dynamic.  If they are not, you store will not work correctly. This [page](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-caching-plugins/) will help you correctly configure your WooCommerce store in conjunction with various mainstream caching plugins.